# Qt creator: where can I find the debugging symbols within my project?

Tags: qt, debugging, qt-creator, config, qmake

I am trying to understand 'qmake' by following [this tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qmake-tutorial.html) . However, when I run my .pro file WITHOUT using CONFIG += debug and then WITH it (to add the debugging symbols), I see no difference. I want to see these debugging symbols, where exactly I can find them within my project ?

I want to see how they can help me as a developer ?

Comment: What are you examining that you see no difference?  The Makefile?  Makefile.Debug?  Makefile.Release?

Answer (score 1):

They should show up in the build directory specified in your project settings in Qt Creator.

With MSVC2010, it creates a `pdb` file in `<Project>/debug` when using Qt Creator.

Here is the qmake line:

```
qmake.exe "C:\path\to\myproject\myproject.pro" -r -spec win32-msvc2010
```

Which is probably getting executed in:

`"C:\path\to\myproject\debug"`

or if you are using shadow building enabled in Qt Creator, it will end up in:

`"C:\path\to\myproject-build-VS2010-<QT_VERSION>__Debug"`

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qmake-manual.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: Any idea for MinGW tool-chains?

Comment: @YamHon.CHAN, they are just embedded into target file.